# How to Query the Same Data within a Table but the Output Row Positions are Different

Tags: mysql

I have a table inside my database just like the sample below and i would like to query the same data but in the Column 2 the positions of the data would be 1 row greater than the previous data.

P.S. Im actually making a system for a Electric Meter Reading and I need the Current(Column 1) and the Previous(Column 2) Data Reading, so that I could compute the total consumption of the Electric Meter. But I am having a hard time doing it. Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated. Thank You. :)

Example data:

[image]

Desired Query Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that SQL table rows *have no inherent order*. They're just bags of records.

You must order them based on some column value or other criterion. In your case I guess you want the most recent and the second most recent meter reading for each account. Presumably your reading table has columns something like this:

```
reading_id    customer_id    datestamp    value
   1            1122         2009-02-11    112
   2            1234         2009-02-13     18
   3            1122         2009-03-08    125
   4            1234         2009-03-10     40
   5            1122         2009-04-12    160
   6            1234         2009-04-11     62
```

I guess you need this sort of result set

```
   customer_id    datestamp   value    previous
    1122          2009-03-08    125        112
    1122          2009-04-12    160        125
    1234         ...etcetera.
```

How can you get this?  For each row in the table, you need a way to find the previous reading for the same customer: that is, the row with

- the same customer id
- the latest datestamp that occurs before the current datestamp.

This is a job for a so-called *correlated subquery.* Here's the query, with its subquery. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hWGAbq4uAbA5f15j7oZY9o/0)

```
SELECT aft.customer_id, 
       aft.datestamp, 
       (  SELECT bef.value
            FROM r bef                               /* row from table.... */
           WHERE bef.datestamp < aft.datestamp       /* with datestamp < present datestamp */
             AND bef.customer_id = aft.customer_id   /* and same customer id */
           ORDER BY bef.datestamp DESC               /* most recent first */
           LIMIT 1                                   /* only most recent */
        ) prev,              
        aft.value
  FROM r aft
 ORDER BY aft.customer_id, aft.datestamp
```

Notice that dealing with the first reading for each customer takes some thought in your business process.